# SWRevealViewController with TabBarcontroller for all views

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I use SWRevealViewController with TabBarcontroller but the problem is the revealpushview does not show the tabbar(i.e red colour view). I know that why because of that view controller is not embded with tabbar controller(i.e redview controller). So how can show the tabbar from that viewcontroller. Redviewcontroller is pushed from the menu.(i.e sw_rear) Please find the below screenshot. Hope someone helps!

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InH5S.png)

Comment: "Redviewcontroller is pushed from the menu" <-- the code that does that must be in error.  Let's see it.

Comment: Yes need to push from the menu but i need the tabbar also. how can i connect from tabbar controller and also push from menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your viewcontroller that has red background color not connected to uitabbarcontroller, see attached picture for details. [image: storyboard]

Comment: The picture might be not so good, but the viewcontrollers on top which I added a red text are connected to tabbar controller so they have tabbar on bottom. But on the below which has blue text on it are not connected to tabbar controller. So there is not any tabbar on bottom.

Comment: @Sureshkumar the way to show tabbar on red background view controller is to open this viewcontroller under the viewcontroller which connected to tabbar. Or if you want a additional tabbar item you can directly connect it with tabbar controller.

Comment: Actually i pushed the red viewcontroller from tableView(i.e. sw_rear) but i also need the tabbar because i need to access the tabbar items also. So how can i do that or how will i connect the tabbarcontroller to the redviewcontroller.

Comment: Your tableview is not connected to tabbar so it is normal not to see tabbar on redviewcontroller. Push tableview from viewcontrollers which are connected to tabbar controller.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution for both access SWRevealViewController and TabbarController.
Please find the below screenshot

[ScreenShot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRKLY.png)

[ScreenShot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv7AX.png)